# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de se usar Wordpress e fazer do zero?

Tags: wordpress, framework, cms

Na faculdade, eu e alguns colegas estamos pensando em desenvolver um projeto e que eventualmente se transformará em algo grande, então foi citado usar o **Wordpress**.

Sendo mais específico, qual é a diferença entre eu usar um **CMS** como **Wordpress** ou usar um **framework** como o **laravel**, **cakePHP**, etc? 
Que vantagens e desvantagens tenho ao usar cada uma dessas opções?

E a questão de **SEO**, qual leva vantagem sobre qual se todos forem bem aplicados?

Comment: A dúvida é interessante, mas não imagino que seja possível uma resposta objetiva que englobe tudo sobre o assunto. Daria uma boa conversa no chat da rede, por exemplo, onde cabem opiniões e discussões mais extensas. Seus pontos já permitem acesso à [sala principal do site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) - Wordpress é muito bom pra quem precisa de Wordpress. Só você sabe o que seu projeto precisa. Lembre-se que grande não é o mesmo que bom. E que quanto mais um sistema quer abraçar o mundo, geralmente mais ele se nivela por baixo, para "agradar a todos".

Comment: Se o wp não tivesse uma "base sólida", ele não seria tão popular quanto é hoje. Ele é um sistema de controle de conteúdo, então ele vai servir para controlar conteúdo. Se você acha que pode peitar (e vá necessitar de) um sistema desse porte, manda bala! =)

Comment: Essa semana passei uma raiva com Wordpress. Se eu fosse falar sobre o assunto, já diria que não é bom usar Wordpress. Por outro lado, começar do zero pode fazer você gastar um tempo precioso. Eu, na minha humilde opinião, preferiria utilizar um Framework, visto que o Wordpress tem vários problemas de segurança.

Comment: Sim, não vou criar totalmente do zero, certamente vou usar um framework, mas quais são as vantagens de se usar um Wordpress ou outro qualquer CMS da vida e em vez de usar um framework ?

Comment: Superficialmente falando, um CMS como Wordpress possui um knowhow enorme e ferramentas essenciais sólidas. Um exemplo, é relativamente fácil construir uma página web a partir do zero usando um framework, mas uma página web não é tão simples. Você vai precisar de uma boa semântica para SEO, por exemplo. Nisso, o WP tem tudo prontinho. Também a questão dos módulos, themes, o marketplace e os "sub-mercados" que nascem em torno disso. Há todo um business enorme por trás do sistema. Esse conjunto inteiro, necessita de muitos anos e uma equipe 100% dedicada e claro, investimentos pesados $$.

Comment: Outro ponto chave é a garantia do sistema. WP é todo documentado, homologado, tem comunidades no mundo todo. Se um programador sair da empresa, basta contratar outro que entenda de WP e está tudo tranquilo. Agora num sistema desconhecido, mesmo que tenha boa documentação, se não tem uma popularidade e comunidade forte, dificilmente encontará alguém apto para dar continuidade. Normalmente  um programador novo vai ver aquilo e dizer "bah!! é melhor começar do zero usando um sistema como wordpress" e provavelmente ele vai usar esses argumentos aqui que normalmente convencem.

Comment: Você também vai ouvir muito a frase  "pra quê reinventar a roda?". Aí depende do seu objetivo em querer reinventar a roda. Se o seu objetivo é para entrar no mercado e competir com as "rodas" já existentes, siga em frente. Apenas responda "não estou reinventando a roda, estou criando uma roda melhor". Afinal, se os criadores originais do Wordpress não tivessem reinventado/melhorado a roda, o WP e todo esse mercado bilionário não existiria. Estaríamos ainda hoje usando o quê? joomla? xoops? ez-publish? E se o joomla não tivesse existido, estaríamos no phpnuke.. e assim vai. Pense no objetivo.

Comment: + 1 por lembrar do xoops